# IOS enterprise distribution Install fails on some ipads - A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted

Tags: ios

We are using the enterprise distribution method, on most devices installation works fine, but and I have this odd error coming up on a few devices. iOS versions are the same, as far as I can see the iPads are more or less identical in configuration.

Comment: Are installing from the server or xcode?

Comment: I do installation from a link on a website